# Why isn't hextoraw() functioning, Am I misunderstanding it?

Tags: oracle

I'm running `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`, and I'm trying to convert a few hex characters to a string:

```
SQL> select hextoraw('414243') from dual;

HEXTOR
------
414243
```

But it seems nothing has been done here, am I miss understanding this macro?

Answer (score 2):

Because the tools displays the result as string, so it seems nothing changed. Actually the datatypes are different, please use below SQL to check:

```
    SQL> SELECT DUMP('414243'),DUMP(HEXTORAW('414243')) from dual 
    A                                B
    -------------------------------- --------------------------------------
    Typ=96 Len=6: 52,49,52,50,52,51  Typ=23 Len=3: 65,66,67
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe SQL*Plus is just formatting the RAW to a format convenient for display.

`HEXTORAW('414243')` converts your string to the `RAW(3)` consisting of `[0x41 0x42 0x43]`. Then, when sqlplus tries to display that value back to the user, it converts it to something it can print to the terminal.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33654) is a SQL Fiddle, but it looks like it displays the RAW value in base-10 format rather than hex. I'm not sure if there is a format command for sqlplus to change this behavior.

```
select hextoraw( '414243' ) as col1, 
       utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2( hextoraw( '414243' )) as col2
from dual;

|     COL1 | COL2 |
|----------|------|
| 65,66,67 |  ABC |
```